# Galaxy Tab 4 not Recognized in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, galaxy-tab

I am running windows 7 and have a Galaxy Tab 4 with Wifi only. I just switched from a different computer to this one, both using Android Studio. My tablet was recognized on the other computer through the ABD, but not the new computer. I have installed the Google Nexus Drivers, the samsung driver, the JDK, and the android SDK. The only thing I have not installed are the Samsung API's because I don't believe that I need them and don't think that they would help. I have switched the Media mode from MTP to PTP several times. Anybody know how to make this work? 
*I have search through all of the questions and answers here and I have not found a solution that works.

Answer (score 7):

Installing the driver from

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/GT-P7510MAVXAB

worked for me. Now I can use a Samsung Galaxy Tab with Android Studio. It is recognized as a running device when you open the "Choose Device" Dialog.

Also, I enabled [Developer Options and USB Debugging](http://www.wugfresh.com/faq/6/). (@Zhuinden pointed that out.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the drivers: 
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Android-USB-Driver-for-Windows;jsessionid=0kzbJL5LhpN4RTpv19GPC1sBJ5GxPsfnpj8wFNXt37hNmx780XRR!1627734913

And you also [need to enable Developer options, and USB Debugging](http://www.wugfresh.com/faq/6/).

What I also tend to do is download the naked drivers from XDA-Developers, 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/development/adb-fb-apx-driver-universal-naked-t2513339

and use `pnputil -i -a winusb.inf` to install it.